# How to use .txt with 3D coords in BVH?

Tags: python, coordinates, motion-capture, bvh

I have 3D coords from a hand mocap , the coords are (x,y,z), there are in a .txt list with 3 cols and each row represents a point. How can I transform them to BVH format? Any script, web, video or reference is welcoming. Thank u.